# Remove Duplicate entries in conf file using ansible with replace/lineinfile module

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to update ssh configuration in Linux using ansible with help of replace and lineinfile module.

My requirements are like,

ssh file contains:

```
PermitRootLogin Yes
#PermitRootLogin Yes
PermitRootLogin yes
permitrootlogin yes
```

My ansible playbook look like:

```
lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/ssh
        regexp: "{{ item.From }}"
        line: "{{ item.To }}"
        state: present
        backrefs: yes
      with_items:
       - { From: '(?i)(.*PermitRootLogin Yes*)', To: '#PermitRootLogin No' }
       - { From: '(?i)(.*#PermitRootLogin Yes*)', To: '' }
       - { From: '(?i)(.*PermitRootLogin Yes*)', To: '' }
```

Expected Results it should be "PermitRootLogin No" only one entry should be there in the configuration file.

But it's not. Can someone help here? I need a single task to complete the activity. It shouldn't be more than that.

Comment: Please format your question appropriately, use the `code` formatting as it's hard to read like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution:

```
- name: PermitRootLogin other than 'No' is absent
  lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/ssh
    state: absent
    regexp: '(?i)^[\s#]*PermitRootLogin\s+[^N][^o]'

- name: PermitRootLogin No is present
  lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/ssh
    state: present
    regexp: '^[\s#]*PermitRootLogin\s'
    line: 'PermitRootLogin No'
```

Don't forget to notify your handler that restarts or reloads sshd.

Comment: Great answer, the unique thing is I don't know if he wants the "to"  "#PermitRootLogin No" in his example its commented, maybe he did a mistake typing it (for me makes no sense to comment it)

Comment: @Rene - I need this task should be on a single task not a multiple.  As you mentioned the first task is not removing the line. Status changed to "OK".                                      - name: PermitRootLogin other than 'Yes' is absent
      lineinfile:
       path: /tmp/sshd_config
       state: absent
       regexp: '(?i)^[\s#]*PermitRootLogin\s+[^Y][^e][^s]'

Comment: Your ssh file, has more content besides those 4 lines?  Also why in only 1 task? There is nothing wrong on using 2 tasks.

Comment: @ikora - the first task is not working fine.. I have updated with "yes". It's not removing the line. Above one I have mentioned.

Comment: Try this regexp: '(?i)^[\s#]*PermitRootLogin\s+[^Y][^e][^s]?' (question mark added). This is because 'No' is one character shorter than 'Yes'. This is a bit ad hoc of course. Why do you need it to be a single task? You can combine the tasks in a block or loop, but what difference does that make?

Comment: My requirement is to do the job in a single task. Even I tried with loop also. It's not working well.

Comment: @PrabaharS Does putting the two tasks in a `block` satisfy your requirement?